How to dynamically manage the 'owners/{ownerUUID}' prefix in Laravel API routes?
In my Laravel application, I have many duplicate routes with the prefix owners/{ownerUUID}. For example, I have a route like this:
GET owners/{ownerUUID}/hotels/{hotelUUID}

This is an API call and I'm wondering if there's a way to pass the ownerUUID in a different manner instead of always including it in the GET route. I'd like to avoid duplicating this part of the route in many similar route definitions. What are the best practices to handle this situation in Laravel? The ownerUUID would be the session in which the user authenticates on the client side.

"I'd like to avoid duplicating this part of the route in many similar route definitions" - have you looked at route groups? https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#route-groups

No, actually that's in the api.php file and it's already organized that way. I meant the method of passing the value directly from the client to the server, avoiding repeating it each time. If it were a single application, I could use session storage for that value, but with an API, I can't do that.

@AndreaVerrecchia, The way  your GET route is defined is the standard as per the REST API naming-convenstions .There is nothing wrong in it. And it is the best practice to follow that you shared in your post.

What you could be looking for is route grouping especially the group prefix.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#route-group-prefixes

the way that you are using routes is totally fine.
if you want to remove ownerUUID and hotelUUID from URL you have to use POST method to send variables to controller.
for example :
route:
Route::post('/owners-hotels', [Controller::class, 'foo'])->name('owners-hotels');

controller:
public function foo(Request $request){

    $ownerUUID = $request->integer('ownerUUID');
    $hotelUUID = $request->integer('hotelUUID');

    // your code
}

then you can send post request to your api...
